Next.js 11 - Axios api call triggering 2 times when page loads
I have been trying to migrate a React.js CRA to Next.js SSR Application, I moved specifically to Next.js 11 as I have some package deps which support only up Next.js 11, as my CRA application is working perfect, but when I moved all my project files to Next.js 11, all my API calls are triggering 2 times when I visit the page, I'm using react 16 and axios to fetch data from my backend, please help me to fix this issue :
Here is sample code :
in pages/test/index.js
"use client"

import React from 'react';
import Test from '../../src/components/test';

const Asdf = () => {
    return ( 
        <Test />
     );
}
 
export default Asdf;

here is the component :
"use client"

import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products/')
        .then(res => setData(res))
    }, [])

    return ( 
        <>
           test page
        </>
     );
}

export default Test;

In network tab, you can notice 4 request, 2 are preflight and rest 2 calls being triggered :

Is there anyways to prevent it or what I'm doing wrong, please let me know! Thanks in advance.

If you're using React 18 or above, it's because React introduces strict mode. It's basically a feature to help you find bugs in the development environment and won't influence the production environment. Here is the note from React's documentation:

Strict Mode enables the following checks in development:

Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.
Your components will be checked for usage of deprecated APIs.
All of these checks are development-only and do not impact the production build.


If you want to avoid this behavior, just go to the next.config file and change the reactStrictMode to false:
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};


You can add reactStrictMode: false in  next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};

Once added don't forget to restart the project
Here you have more info!
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode
